# Generate XML files with Japanese characters using NiFi

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I am converting a JSON payload to XML file using Python ExecuteScript processor in NiFi.
The JSON looks like this :

```json
{
  "Header": {
    "Att1": 1,
    "Att2": "value2",
    "Att3": "1",
    "Att4": "경기00자123"
  }
}
```

The python script to convert this JSON to XML is as below :

```
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

class ModJSON(StreamCallback):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        data = json.loads(text)
        root = ET.Element("headerinfo")
        entity = ET.SubElement(root, "headerfile")
        ET.SubElement(entity, "Att1").text = str(data["Header"]["Att1"])
        ET.SubElement(entity, "Att2").text = str(data["Header"]["Att2"])
        ET.SubElement(entity, "Att3").text = str(data["Header"]["Att3"])
        ET.SubElement(entity, "Att4").text = data["Header"]["Att4"].encode("utf8")
        xmlNew = ET.tostring(root)
        outputStream.write(bytearray(xmlNew))

flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile != None:
    try :
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, ModJSON())
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filename", 'headerfile.xml')
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile,'python_error', str(e))
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
```

No matter how I try to encode the Att4 with Japanese characters, it looks like this in the resulting XML :

```
&#228;&#186;&#172;&#233;&#131;&#189;111&#227;&#130;&#146;3
```

How can I change the code to fix this?
Tried a lot of different things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try arguments of ElementTree.tostring .. it supports encoding and mode.

Comment: @daggett Thanks for the suggestion! Tried it and got this error - "write(): 1st arg can't be coerced to byte[], int"

Comment: try write(xmlNew.encode('utf-8'))  or whatever encoding you used for xml.tostring

Comment: Thanks for your comments @daggett 
Tried the stuff you mentioned, it doesn't throw an error, but the data still looks like this : 
`&#20140;&#37117;111&#12434;3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems there is an issue with byte-string in jython - they are automatically converted to str object with incorrect encoding.

however ElementTree has [write](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) function that could write to a file-like object and [OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) (java object) actually implements write function - so, we could make ElementTree write directly to OutputStream

```
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

class ModJSON(StreamCallback):
    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        data = json.loads(text)
        root = ET.Element("headerinfo")
        entity = ET.SubElement(root, "headerfile")
        ET.SubElement(entity, "Att1").text = str(data["Header"]["Att1"])
        ET.SubElement(entity, "Att2").text = str(data["Header"]["Att2"])
        ET.SubElement(entity, "Att3").text = str(data["Header"]["Att3"])
        ET.SubElement(entity, "Att4").text = data["Header"]["Att4"]
        ET.ElementTree(root).write(outputStream, encoding='utf-8')

flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile != None:
    try :
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, ModJSON())
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filename", 'headerfile.xml')
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile,'python_error', str(e))
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
```

Comment: Yes this works! Thanks a lot @dagget